# Full width container text box in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make my code to use full width of the device? I am using bootstrap.

```
    <section class="special-area bg-white section_padding_100" id="about">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <!-- Section Heading Area -->
                        <div class="section-heading text-center">
                            <h2>Why Is It Special</h2>
                            <div class="line-shape"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="row">
                <!-- Single Special Area -->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="single-special text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                        <div class="single-icon">
                            <i class="ti-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Heading</h4>
                        <p>Some text here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: use container-fluid instead of container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include those parts of your code inside a pre-defined div whose class name is `container-fluid`. Here are the properties of `container-fluid`:

```
.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

You can also add a 100% width style to any other container as well, but maybe that can collide with other style rules of your CSS.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

you have to use

```
class="container-fluid"
```

instead of container class because container class itself has paddings from the right and left...

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/):

> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.

Just make sure it is your outermost element.